# Buttons in allow access to your location disabled

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, core-location

my viewController looks like following

```
import CoreLocation

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            let lon = locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude
            let lat = locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude
            print("lat = \(lat) and long = \(lon)")
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

extension MyViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

When I execute my program, it prompts a message like

> Allow application to access your location while you use the app?

But the **Don't Allow** and **Allow** buttons are *disabled*.

Can someone guide me on where I am going wrong and what I should be doing.

I can manually allow my application to access location services by going to settings. But I would like to know why the buttons are disabled and what should I do to enable it.

note: I have added **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** to my info.plist file.

Thanks.

> Dt: 29Oct2015

**EDIT:**
Uninstalled the app and installed again and tried. Now I am able to access the buttons.

Also, I noticed that sometimes the screen goes unresponsive i.e., screen cannot take any input from user. I noticed it today with a textbox. I am not able to get the cursor to the text box.

Is it something to do with IOS update? is anyone else experiencing this type of weird behaviour. Is there any workaround for the same?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Few more information, 1) The location services are turned on in the device. 2) I tried to place the block to request authorisation under `ViewDidLoad` and it is the same.

Comment: Do you have `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key present in your Info.plist ?

Comment: @ZellB. Yes. I have mentioned that in my question (under note:) also.

Comment: Just tried your code and its working on my device. Maybe show us your full code (if there's more)

Comment: @ZellB. The code is working for me too now. Not sure why sometimes the device goes unresponsive.

Comment: "Also, I noticed that sometimes the screen goes unresponsive i.e., screen cannot take any input from user." Any time that happens, it means you've either accidentally disabled user interaction, or you've done some long-running process on the main thread when you should be using a background thread. But whatever that may be, it is not shown in the code you provided.